# My Tkinter image button is too big! How do I fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Basically I have a Tesla png that is a button. When it was just a button (without image) it was the perfect default size, but the image is gigantic. **How do I make it smaller?**
Here is my code:

,,,

```
screen = tkinter.Tk()

screen.geometry('800x600')
screen['bg'] = 'red'
screen.title("sm reasons")

text = tkinter.Label(screen, text=generateSentence(), bg='red', fg= 'white', font=("Arial", 24))
text.pack()

imagetest = PhotoImage(file = r"/Users//sasha//PycharmProjects//Birthday//venv//teslalogo.png")

btn = tkinter.Button(screen, image = imagetest, command=buttonAction)
text.grid(row=0, column=0)
btn.grid(row=1, column=0)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Simply resize the image to the desired size using a image editing application.

Answer (score 1):

so what you're looking for is the `.subsample` function which will resize your `.png` and to then call the resized photo in your button.

```
from tkinter import *
screen = Tk()

screen.geometry('800x600')
screen['bg'] = 'red'
screen.title("sm reasons")

text = Label(screen, bg='red', fg= 'white', font=("Arial", 24))
text.pack()

imagetest = PhotoImage(file = '')

# Resizing image to fit on button 
photoimage = imagetest.subsample(3, 3) 
btn = Button(screen, image = photoimage)

text.grid(row=0, column=0)
btn.grid(row=1, column=0)

screen.mainloop()
```